# How to validate submitted Token

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin, openid-connect

I have an angularJs application which connects with a third party authentication server to get users authenticated. In response the authentication server returns a token, which angularJs application submits to my another project asp.net web api.

Now the problem is how can I validate the token from the authentication server weather it is valid token? I am new to external authentication and please refer some article

Comment: Validating tokens (globally) from the server is usually done in [response interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), the validation logic runs **before** the tokens reach your $http promise handlers

Answer (score 0):

Usually third party authentication service signs tokens using asymmetric signing. The token is signed by a private key stored in the third party service.

You can validate the token using the corresponding public key, which can be obtained by the discovery process from your third party authentication provider.

By verifying the signature of your token using the public key, you can check the validity of the token.

The general relation between your client, your resource server and the third party authentication provider can be found in the following auth0 article:

https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/server-api/part-1